# Need to read Struct variable fom OPC UA Server with OPC UA .NET from opcfoundation

Tags: opc-ua

I'm new to OPC UA.
I'm using

- OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.Client (1.4.368.58)
- OPC Server opc.tcp://opcuaserver.com:48010
- Node to read : ns=2;s=Demo.WorkOrder.WorkOrderVariable

This structure contains simple types (Guid, Int64, String, etc...) and a custom types "WorkOrderStatusType"

I can read values with : session.ReadValues(...) and process with :

```
    var encodeable = val as ExtensionObject;
    var decoder = new BinaryDecoder(encodeable.Body as byte[], ServiceMessageContext.GlobalContext);
    decoder.ReadGuid("ID");
```

It works for simple types but not for custom types.
I would like to know how to parse sub custom types.

I've searched a lot and can't find anything specific to understand.

I would like to create an object myself and have the OPC library automatically map my object, but I don't know how.

Could you help me ?

Thank you.